# How to disable log4j2's auto initialization in console application?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

How to disable log4j2's auto initialization in console application? I know it can be disable in servlet context by

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but, how in in console application? I guess:

```
System.setProperty("isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled", "true");
```

and I tried, but not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Log4j2 initializes, it needs a configuration. The default configuration is where all ERROR messages are logged to the console, and other messages are ignored.

This is usually not what you want, and you can change this by supplying a configuration that meets your needs. The most common way to do this is to create a file `log4j2.xml` and put this in the classpath. The configuration file [syntax](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) is well documented in the user manual with many, many examples. Especially the pages on [appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) and [layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) may be of interest.

Log4j2 also supports configuration files in JSON, YAML and properties format (different from the Log4j-1.2 format!), but most of the examples in the manual are xml.

Finally, you can specify the location of the configuration file with system property `log4j.configurationFile`, so it doesn't *have* to be on the classpath.

If you have trouble with the configuration, use `<Configuration status="trace">` at the top of your configuration file to print internal Log4j2 status messages to the console. (Use `WARN` to switch it off.)

Since Log4j 2.9, you can enable internal status logging by specifying system property `log4j2.debug` (without a value). This should help with troubleshooting.